# Can't install new icon themes & system theme problems

Tags: lubuntu, icons, themes, lxde

When trying to install a new icon theme, nothing happens. Using lxappearance in LXDE with a new clean install of Ubuntu 16.04.6.

- click install new theme
- choose archive (tar.gz or tar.bz2 are the
  only recognized types)
- choose tar.gz file & click open
- dialogue box pops up so quick I can't see what it says or if it says anything at all
- nothing changes, no new theme appears in list

Also I have chosen the "onyx" window border theme (I assumed this was the system theme as well); however, when I change the task bar to "system theme". it just goes white.

What the heck is going on? I just want my new install to look like my previous one but everything is different this time around.

Comment: If you just clean installed Lubuntu 16.04.6, I would forget about it, and start again with Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.  The Lubuntu team didn't put out a 16.04.6 release document as they like all flavors reached EOL in April-2019 which wasn't long after 16.04.6 came out http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/.  Yes Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (no desktop), Ubuntu Desktop (Unity) 16.04 LTS come with 5 years of support, other flavors only come with 3 years of support which is now gone.  If you want LXDE, I'd consider moving to 18.04 LTS, or use no desktop (server) or Unity 7.

Comment: Did you try extracting the icon and system themes and copying them to `~/.icons` and `~/.themes` folders respectively?

Comment: @ user3140225 IT WORKS! thankyou so much :) feels like home again.